# Sphere from point on the GPU

Tags: 3d, shader, geometry-shader

I have a mesh that consists of line lists (pairs of vertices).
I would like to create a sphere on the GPU for every even vertex, centered on that vertex. Resolution of the sphere is not immediately important.
Would a geometry shader be the way to do it, and if so - how?

Comment: for each vertex generate single quad and render sphere like sprite with it, you would need to have 2 pass rendering in one draw the lines in the other the quads ... if you do not want to add the billboard techniques then add 3 perpendicular quads instead of one per vertex